# What is the name of this insect? It is from Punjab, India

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

What is the name of this insect? It is from Punjab, India.[image]

Comment: It seems to be a bug that belongs the family *Rhyparochrominae* from the tribe *Myodochini*.
https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Myodochini

There are too many species for an inexperienced person like myself to know which particular one this photo belongs to. 

These species I believe are known as seed bugs.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit] your post to include the size of this creature. The size can be an essential clue for identifications. ———  Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 